# How to add a permanent prefix to a textbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, watermark

I would like a variation on a watermark for a textbox. But I don't want the watermark to go away. I want it to act like a prefix that can't be typed over or removed. I don't want to use an HTML/CSS solution such as:

```
 <div style="border: solid 1px black; width:250px;">
   <label style="border:none;">prefix_</label>
   <input type="text" style="border:none;"/>
 </div>
```

I even want the prefix submitted as part of the textbox value. I would like a jquery solution. But I must not be using the right keywords to search because I can't find one. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

This would handle keeping the prefix permanent:

```
$('#field').keyup(function() {
  var prefix = 'string'
  if (this.value.substring(0, prefix.length) != prefix){
    $(this).val(prefix)
  }
});​
```

Comment: Would need to bind the same to `.onblur()` to prevent the ability to mouse-paste over the prefix...

Comment: This seems close. I can still use home or the mouse to change my cursor position and alter the prefix but the changes are not kept. I wish this behavior could be improved so that the changes are actually ignored instead of done then undone.

Comment: @ShawnDoe don't think that's possible - you could bind to `.keydown`, but there's nothing (I know of) to block the character being typed...

Answer (score 1):

You could prepend the prefix upon submitting the textbox. Like this you will not have to handle users trying to remove the prefix.

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function{
    var valueiwant = "myprefix "+$('#textfield').val();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have considered that but I want the user to know that the input they enter is not what is stored. Right now I just have the prefix as a label to the left of the textbox but I wanted to improve on that.

Comment: Considering the pros and cons of the other answers, this might be the best solution...  If you use labels properly (tooltips, etc) then the user will know what they entered is going to get a prefix prepended to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (Nicola Peluchetti's answer with some slight modifications)

Makes no effort to retain user's input if they mess with the prefix:

http://jsfiddle.net/vBBpS/2/

Attempts to retain user's input:

http://jsfiddle.net/vBBpS/1/

Comment: If I delete a single character from the end of the prefix, I get almost double prefix ('prefix_' -> 'prefix_prefix')

Comment: If I press the backspace before doing anything else I get "prefix_prefix". I was really hoping there was already a plugin in use but couldn't find it with my search of textbox prefix and textbox prepend.

Comment: Ah, good catch. This is flawed. It is a start though. At least it also takes binding to blur into account.

Comment: I edited it to show a solution where you don't keep the user's input if they mess with the prefix.  Keeping the user's input obviously gets more complex if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you'd add it to the text box (so it's not removable) but you could just add the prefix when calling the value of the text box.
For example:

```
<input type = 'text' id = 'inputID' />

<script type = 'text/javascript'>
  var MyVar = document.getElementById('inputID').value;
  var finalVar = "prefix_" + MyVar;
  MyVar.value = finalVar;
</script>
```

attach it to an "onclick function" or "onKeydown" function

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/5n6WF/

```
$(function() {
    $('#field').val($('#field').data('prefix'));

    original_value = $('#field').val();

    $('#field').keyup(function() {
        var f      = $(this),
            prefix = f.data('prefix'),
            rx     = new RegExp('^' + escape(prefix));

        new_value = prefix + unescape(escape(f.val()).replace(rx, ''));

        if (original_value != new_value) {
            original_value = new_value;
            f.val(new_value);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I can't tell if this will work because I can use the mouse to put the cursor at the beginning and when I type "Q" I see "some prefixQsome prefix" in the box.

Comment: This has the same bug as Matt Cofer's answer - delete a single character and the entire prefix is prefixed again, along with the previously modified prefix.